# Page design like this

Tags: tikz-pgf, book-design

Can any one help me design something like this?.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think this layout can be done with [tikz-page](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-page).

Comment: Since i'm new to latex , i tried tikz but i couldn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to use TikZ:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{forloop}

\usepackage{mwe}% <--- for testing purpose only

\newlength{\mytoph}
\setlength{\mytoph}{.75\paperheight}
\newlength{\mytopw}
\setlength{\mytopw}{.75\paperheight}
\newlength{\mytophincr}
\setlength{\mytophincr}{-1cm}
\newlength{\mytopwincr}
\setlength{\mytopwincr}{.8cm}
\newcounter{mycount}
\newsavebox{\myvertline}
\savebox{\myvertline}{%
    \color{cyan!30}\makebox[0cm][l]{\rule[\mytoph]{1cm}{\mytopw}}%
    \addtolength{\mytoph}{\mytophincr}%
    \setlength{\mytopw}{\mytopwincr}%
    \makebox[0cm][l]{\rule[\mytoph]{1cm}{\mytopw}}%
    \forloop{mycount}{0}{\value{mycount}<10}{%
      \addtolength{\mytophincr}{.05cm}%
      \addtolength{\mytopwincr}{-.08cm}%
      \addtolength{\mytoph}{\mytophincr}%
      \setlength{\mytopw}{\mytopwincr}%
      \makebox[0cm][l]{\rule[\mytoph]{1cm}{\mytopw}}%
    }%
}

\newlength{\whitegap}
\setlength{\whitegap}{.6cm}
\newlength{\bluew}
\setlength{\bluew}{.2cm}
\newsavebox{\myhorline}
\savebox{\myhorline}{%
    \color{cyan}%
    \forloop{mycount}{0}{\value{mycount}<5}{%
      \rule{\whitegap}{0cm}\rule{\bluew}{1cm}%
      \addtolength{\whitegap}{-.1cm}%
      \addtolength{\bluew}{.2cm}%
    }%
}

\newlength{\topgap}
\setlength{\topgap}{\paperwidth}
\addtolength{\topgap}{-1cm}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
    \usebox{\myvertline}\rule{\topgap}{0cm}\usebox{\myvertline}%
    \hspace{-\topgap}\color{cyan}%
    \makebox[0cm][l]{\usebox{\myhorline}}\hspace{\paperwidth}\makebox[0cm][r]{\reflectbox{\usebox{\myhorline}}}%
}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[10]% <--- for testing purpose only
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @JackAlbert You're welcome!